# Number of solutions of the congruence $x^p \equiv x\pmod p$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic

How do I show that $x^p \equiv x\pmod p$ has precisely $p$ solutions?

I can use Lagrange's theorem and Fermat's little theorem.

Comment: Is $p{}$ prime?

Comment: sorry, yes p is prime

Comment: which aspect is confusing to you?

Comment: Lagranges theorem shows that x^p-x=0 (mod p) has at most p solutions, I cant figure out the next step to show it has precisely p solutions, using these two theorems,

Comment: there are p distinct numbers between 0 and p-1, each one is a solution

Comment: @cf12418: Fermat's Little Theorem says there are at least $p$ solutions ($0\dots p-1$).

Comment: See http://math453fall2008.wikidot.com/lecture-23

Comment: What theorem of Lagrange are you using to deduce it has at most $p$ roots?

Answer (score 1):

The formula you expressed holds always when p is a prime.(Fermat's Little Theorem).
Lagrange's theorem is useful usually when dealing with the order of subgroups.
How familiar are you with modular arithmetic? One way of describing "mod p" is that there are p possible remainders when dividing something mod p. For example, when dividing by 3, you could end up with a remainder of 0,1, or 2. Notice that is three possible "solutions", for mod 3. So in mod p, there will be p possible solutions.  Hope that helps...